# In Reactjs how to fetch data from server either from componentDidMount or from constructor

Tags: reactjs, constructor

I have to fetch data from the server to render the page. In case the server is down or data fetch fails for some reason, I have no data to show. I could show the server is down error message. My data fetch call is in componentDidMount here:-

```
async componentDidMount() {

    this.setState({ profiles: await CurdApi.getAllProfiles() });
}
```

But render() is called before componentDidMount. So I am thinking to call `CurdApi.getAllProfiles()`  from componentWillUnmount or from the constructor. But componentWillUnmount is deprecated. So the option is to call from the constructor. I am new in  Reactjs so I don't know is recommended to call any API which fetches data from the server in the constructor? Or is there any other way?

Comment: Can you provide the complete code for the component along with render function. You need to conditionally render state based on this.state.profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Always use mount for data (or componentDidUpdate [its a little harder though])

You can use constructor to setup some defaults but sue your mount for data fetching. Use try catch to capture errors. Before rendering data please check some values like is there an error? is there data in profiles? is there a loading state?

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    profiles: [],
    isLoading: true,
  }
}

async componentDidMount() {
  try {
    let profiles = await CurdApi.getAllProfiles();
    this.setState({ profiles, error: null, isLoading: false });
  } catch (error) {
    let error = error.message;
    this.setState({ error, isLoading: false });
  }
}

render(){
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {this.state.isLoading && <Spinner />}
      {this.state.error && <p>this.state.error</p>}
      {this.state.profiles.map(profile => <Profile key={profile.key} {...profile} >)}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Comment: <Spinner /> comes from which library?   I couldn't find it. Sorry, I am new in Reactjs

Comment: Spinner and Profile are just examples of components that you might have made for this purpose. They are not important, the structure is important.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
componentDidMount() {
this.apiCall()
}
...

const apiCall = () => {
this.setState({ profiles: await CurdApi.getAllProfiles() });
}

...

render() {
return(<div>{this.state.profiles ? this.state.profiles : null}</div>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `componentWillMount` and not `componentWillUnmount` here, right? I would recommend using `componentDidMount`. Thats the react way, which is why `useEffect` doesn't even support `componentWillMount` (can't find the reference...).

Essentially you just have to block the page from showing while its loading your data:

```
...
async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ profiles: await CurdApi.getAllProfiles() });
}
....
render(){
   <>
     {state.profiles && <Profiles profiles={profiles} />}
   </>
}
```

I would recommend you using hooks tho, I find it way easier to work with hooks:

```
...

const [state, setState] = useState({});

const fetchProfiles = async() =>{
  setState({ profiles: await CurdApi.getAllProfiles()});
}

useEffect(()=>{
   fetchProfiles();
}, [])

return(
   <>
     {state.profiles && <Profiles profiles={profiles} />}
   </>
)
...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
async componentDidMount() {
 await CurdApi.getAllProfiles().then(resp=>{
    this.setState({ profiles: resp});
 })
}
```